# MC34063A step up voltage converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-up, mc34063

i need change 5v to 12v that it use to supply a device;
for this use MC34063A step up voltage converter;
this [site](http://www.gmsystems.com/switching-reg-calculator-for-mc-34063-or-mc33063.html) can calculate the parameter.

i have problem all thinks is OK but i have same voltage at output!

how to find my mistake ?

[image: MC34063A step up]

[image: MC34063A step up2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pin 2 is not grounded so it does not work.

Comment: ok, Thank you, i check it , now worked.